# Can a router fake the communication to the next nodes on the path?

Tags: security

I have a theoretical question for understanding the safety of TOR:

When I connect to a node A as a first router on my path and I tell him to forward a handshake message to a second node, then how do I know, that he really did forward the message to that node and did not answer it by himself or send it to a friend node?

In theory it would be possible, that a router fakes all the nodes behind him, creates all keys by himself and breaks all the layers of the communication. Is there a mechanism that prevents this?